# Send offline past events to Google Analytics 360

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

How would you send offline events and antidate them of more than 4 hours (which is the limit of the qt param)?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use  measurement protocol** (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1) to send offline events to Google Analytics, **but you cannot** place them in the past (the moment when the hit arrives in Google Analytics is authentic).